# Calculate time needed for sales to hit growth target

Tags: excel

I have a number of client accounts with specified growth targets once fully ramped up. I also have  number of months of sales history per client account; the length of history differs since accounts were set up at different times.

I have then calculated the compounded growth rate for each client account. Now I would like to calculate the number of months it will take for a specific client to reach their sales targets, and for some reason I do not seem to find the right function.

Comment: Thanks. So far I have only the average monthly growth rate. Perhaps it makes sense to simplify the problem to: In how many months do I get from value x to value y, assuming that x grows at a rate r per month (so a compounded growth rate)?

Comment: You could likely do it in a single function, but I tend to show the work. Take current sales, grow it month by month (visible in the sheet) to past the desired sales target. Then you can use a formula to pull which month end with more than the sales target. I always find that if I think it is complicated, it's best to walk through it step by step, then if I come up with a formula to do it all, it's easier to test it. Without more details it's hard to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Matthias I've added a possible solution from what I understood from the question. If it doesn't match what you're after can you add an example.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from the question without an example, the number of months to reach a target can be calculated using `=LOG((a/b),c)` where a is the target, b is the starting value and c is the monthly growth rate (assuming its 1.05 to represent 5% growth)